# How to convert date with suffix to another format in python

Tags: python, date, converters

I need to convert something like:

```
Mar 31st, 2014
Aug 13th, 2014
Sep 2nd, 2014
```

Into:

```
31/03/2014
13/08/2014
2/09/2014
```

I've been looking at strptime but the suffixes are getting in the way. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`dateutil`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) module:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> s = 'Mar 31st, 2014'
>>> parse(s)
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 31, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you!! a = parse(date)
released = a.day.__str__()+"/"+a.month.__str__()+"/"+a.year.__str__()

Comment: Your month will not be zero-leaded, as you show in desired example output. Also it's a bad sign that you explicitly go for private methods (`__str__`). Use `'{0.day}{0:/%m/%Y}'.format(a)` instead

Comment: Why is it bad in this specific case?

Answer (score 1):

You could define your own function to do this:

```
d = {'Jan': '01', 'Feb': '02', 'Mar': '03', 'Apr': '04', 'May': '05', 'Jun': '06', 'Jul': '07', 'Aug': '08', 'Sep': '09', 'Oct': '10', 'Nov': '11', 'Dec': '12'}


def parser(date):
    date = date.split()    # date = ['Mar', '31st,', '2014']
    for i, elem in enumerate(date):
        if i == 0:
            month = d[elem]    # month = '03'
        elif i == 1:
            date = elem[:len(elem) - 3]    # date = '31'
        else:
            year = elem    # year = '2014'
    return date + "/" + month + "/" + year    # '31/03/2014'

print parser('Mar 31st, 2014')
```

This will return `31/03/2014`

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with using standard python modules that there are no format option for days with suffixes (I mean 'st', 'nd', 'th'..), and no option for day without leading zeros.
As for suffixes, you can delete them safely, cause they don't appear in month names. As for day without leading zeros, we can construct string from explicitly selecting date parts.

```
from datetime import datetime 

def convert(dt_string, in_format='%b %d, %Y', out_format='{0.day}{0:/%m/%Y}'):
    for suffix in ('st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th'):
        dt_string = dt_string.replace(suffix, '')
    return out_format.format(datetime.strptime(dt_string, in_format))


dates = ['Mar 31st, 2014', 'Aug 13th, 2014', 'Sep 2nd, 2014']
print map(convert, dates)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the below approach.

```
import datetime
import re

# Collect all dates into a list.
dates = [ 'Mar 31st, 2014', 'Aug 13th, 2014', 'Sep 2nd, 2014' ]

# Compile a pattern to replace alpha digits in date to empty string.
pattern = re.compile('(st|nd|rd|th|,)')

# Itegrate through the list and replace the old format to the new one.
for offset, date in enumerate(dates):
    date = pattern.sub('', date)
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%b %d %Y')
    dates[offset] = str(date.day) + '/' + str(date.month) + '/' + str(date.year)
    print(dates[offset]);
```